# How to disable win10 shrink window when put a window to left edge

Tags: windows, windows-10, partitioning, multiple-monitors

I have dual monitor. 
In windows 7, I usually like put two or three windows in left monitor, the quick way is :

1. move window 1 to left edge, Windows auto resize it to haft window size
2. move window 2 to left edge, Windows auto resize it to haft window size, move window 2 to right part of left monitor. (if need three, need adjust their width)

But in windows 10:

2. move window 2 to left edge would happen:

[image]

Here, window 2 replace window 1, and window 1 be shinked. Need one more click to restore window 1 and two more movements to make window 1 in left part of left monitor, window 2 in right part of left monitor.

You should know, because of dual monitor, move window 2 to right edge of left monitor would not auto resize itself to half window size.

How can I disable this shrink in windows 10 ??? I'd like the windows 7 style, no shrink, don't swap window 1 and window 2 position

Comment: Did you consider using the shotcut Win+Arrow Key to arrange them like you want? Does that show the same behavior?

Comment: @Seth But I'd like to use mouse to do this.. WIN + arrow can resize window 2 to half window, however, I still need use mouse to move window 2 to correct position. it is not so efficient.

Comment: Using Win+Left Arrow or Right Arrow will also move them to the corresponding position. With your response I assume this doesn't show the behavior you're seeing? If you really want to use the Mouse this isn't a solution but it would show whenever the behavior is tied to mouse usage.